# Find top n domain url from the huge log file having all unstructured data with urls

Tags: linux

I was asked to do "Find top n domain url from the huge log file having all unstructured data with urls ". Can it be done using linux command? Do we have to use split command to split the file ?

Comment: So that would be something like `grep`ing with a regex matching domains, `sort`ing and then counting. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: cat linuxcommandtest.txt | grep -o '<someregextofilterdomain>' | sort | uniq  -c but interviewer kept saying that file is too huge and find just top 5

Comment: tell interviewer that with you in charge. you'd take care of not letting grow logfiles too large to handle, then they can be sorted, and sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -5 approach would work. Strange logfiles that must be, with unstructured data

Comment: use some language to count the domains.

Comment: Thanks you all for comments. I really appreciate that. Now I think more do they want to hear about MapReduce approach ?